# How to find a list of rows from grid using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, grid, staleelementreferenceexception

I have a scenario in my framework to get the row count and select one or multiple rows from the grid. Here, the class name and attributes are the same for all rows, the id is kept on changing for each row.

[image: [attached a screenshot][1].]

I've written this xpath to get header checkbox. However, it thrown stale element exception. I'm attaching the DOM here.
[image]

Comment: Add code trial and HTML snippet instead of image for better response

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get count, get as element list size by

```
By appct = By.xpath("//input[@class='ag-input-field ag-checkbox-input']");
int count = driver.findElements(appct).size();
```

and if you want click first two check boxes,

```
if(count > 2){
      driver.findElements(appct).get(0).click();
      driver.findElements(appct).get(1).click();
}
```